# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: jQuery is not defined error in robot framework

Tags: jquery, python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am using Selenium2Library '1.7.4' and Robot Framework 2.9.2 (Python 2.7.8 on win32). If I try to give locator as jQuery, the following exception occurs: `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: jQuery is not defined`. Please advise which version of Selenium2Library and 'Robot Framework' combination works to identify jQuery as a locator.

Comment: Does the page you're trying to test use jquery?

Comment: Yes i am able to identify the locator using jQuery on the console window of the browser. But if i tried to give the same in Robot Framework like "jquery=div.class_name" it throws the exception 'jQuery is not defined'

Comment: Does your jquery load before of after the call?

Comment: We had a similar problem and found that a frame or an iframe on the page was the cause of this error. Check the DOM to see if there is a frame/iframe present on the page, and if the the element you are locating is inside it. If it is, select the frame using the Select Frame keyword and then locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

From Selenium 3.0 - Gecko driver is required to run automation scripts in firefox

Selenium version less than 3.0 works.

Try with the following versions:

- robotframework (3.0.2)
- robotframework-selenium2library (1.8.0)
- selenium (2.53.1)